# Git fingerprint doesn't match with the Azure

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops

I am trying to set up ssh with azure following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#newkeys. After typing

```
ssh -T git@ssh.dev.azure.com
```

, got following message

```
The authenticity of host 'ssh.dev.azure.com (...)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:7o0gWatB......
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

However, this fingerprint doesn't match with the Azure server figerprint. Is it something expected? Should I continue connecting?

Comment: Have you had a chance to check the provided solution?

Comment: Hi, sorry. I overlooked the answer. Will test it tomorrow and update you. Thanks for providing the solution.

Answer (score 2):

This message is usually shown when you're connecting to that server for the first time. You should verify that the displayed fingerprint matches one of the fingerprints in the **SSH public keys** page at: [https://dev.azure.com/{your-organization}/_usersSettings/keys](https://dev.azure.com/%7Byour-organization%7D/_usersSettings/keys)

[image: SSH message]

[image: SSH Public Keys]

SSH displays this fingerprint when it connects to an unknown host to protect you from man-in-the-middle attacks. Once you accept the host's fingerprint, SSH will not prompt you again unless the fingerprint changes.

When you are asked if you want to continue connecting, type `yes` post verification. Git will clone the repo and set up the origin remote to connect with SSH for future Git commands.

Comment: @bhagavi-annadevara, i am facing same issue, after pressing yes, it asks for password.