# How to mirror an Azure DevOps repository to a gitlab one

Tags: git, azure, ssh, azure-devops, gitlab

I have deployed my own GitLab server on an Azure vm.

I was trying to mirror an existing Azure DevOps repository into a GitLab one.

I have followed the normal procedure:

- going to /settings/repository#js-push-remote-settings on GitLab.
- Expanding the mirroring panel.
- I enter my git repo ssh URL

  ```
  ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com/v3/xxx/xxx/xxx
  ```
- here I replaced the original `:` by `/` in front of the `v3`
- I then added the public key generated by GitLab into my Azure DevOps public key.

When triggering the mirroring, I am getting the following error.

```
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote
```

From my research, it is a fingerprint issue.

However, how can I validate this fingerprint?

Answer (score 0):

To [verify the remote GitLab server SSH key](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/ssh_keys/#verifying-the-ssh-host-keys), you could [manually record the SSH key by running](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops#q-after-running-git-clone-i-get-the-following-error-what-should-i-do) ([issue 8867](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-devops-docs/issues/8867))

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa ssh.dev.azure.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

It is a good idea to check if the output of that command matches the server SHA256 fingerprint mentioned by the web page of your repository, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67016547/6309):

[image: fingerprint]

Comment: tried it, I well verified that the command: ssh-keyscan -t rsa ssh.dev.azure.com is returning a key with the good MD5 signature. I also verified that the known_hosts file contains the proper key. however when trying to trigger the mirroring I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @hak Can you try with `ssh -Tv ...` in order to confirm the expected files are indeed used by your SSH query? Including the known_hosts where you see the proper key?